# How to get rid of "click to activate and use this control" prompt for Flash in IE?

Tags: flash, internet-explorer

Our client is getting "click to activate and use this control" over our Flash component in IE.  What's a good fix?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Is this something that SWFObject fixes?  We're using the standard Flash embed code...

Comment: I thought that was gone in the latest fully-patched versions of IE... ?

Comment: And, ironically, recently added as an option in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's plenty of drop-in workaround scripts to automate the bypass of the click-to-activate garbage. This was the first result in a quick googling: http://www.mix-fx.com/flash-prompt.htm

Background: Microsoft got sued by a patent troll over embedded "active" content in a page. But the patent only covered stuff that activate automatically (e.g. on page load). So Microsoft add the click-to-activate workaround to bypass the patent's coverage.

Standard fixes are to use Javascript to loop over all the object elements in a page and basically do:

```
obj.outerHTML = obj.outerHTML
```

on each one, which is enough to appease the workaround's requirements and limit the patent trolls to only a dozen Ferraris each.

Comment: Does this mean workarounds are needed for ALL Flash elements on ALL versions of IE??

Comment: It's not just flash. It's anything ActiveX and/or loaded via object/embed tags. Flash is just the most visible victim. Older IE versions from 5.x on downwards won't have the workaround, as they were EOL'd by Microsoft before the patent suit hit... but if you're targeting something new at browsers that ancient, sit back and think hard about where you're going in life.

Answer (score 1):

You have to embed your SWF with external code. [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) is the de-facto standard for that (and overall it makes the whole embedding much simpler).